# MSOXMLMF.DLL Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: visual-c++, com, visual-studio-2012, migration

I have migrated a project from Visual studio 2008 to Visual Studio 2012. After migration, I am not able to run the application because it is throwing 
`C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSOXMLMF.DLL. Cannot find or open the PDB file.`  message on the output window and my application is getting aborted.

Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: It is not "throwing" anything.  It is just a message from the debugger that it doesn't have debugging symbols for this Office dll.  Which is entirely normal if you don't work for Microsoft.  Whatever causes the abort is something completely different.

Comment: What to you mean by "not able to run"? You can run it, it is just that debugging info is not loaded. And this is not "throw", as @HansPassant mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your application with WinDbg
issue the ".reload" command as:

```
.reload /f SRV*D:\MySymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

The part between the ** is a path on your system. The command will download the matching symbol files for all loaded modules.

Comment: This article explains the process in more detail: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503